# How to properly bind form data to an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components

It might be a bit difficult for me to explain this, but let's see...

I have created a simple Angular 1.5 component, looks like this:

```
( function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module( 'web' )
    .component( 'blockHeading', {
      templateUrl: 'components/blocks/heading/blockHeading.tmpl',
      bindings: {
        title: '@',
        subtitle: '@',
      },
    });

})();
```

The template (blockHeading.tmpl) looks like this:

```
<h2 ng-if="$ctrl.title">{{ $ctrl.title }}</h2>
<h4 ng-if="$ctrl.subtitle">{{ $ctrl.subtitle }}</h4>
```

On the frontend of my application, I can display one of these components like so:

```
<block-heading class="component-block" title="Title of component" subtitle="This is a small blurb"></block-heading>
```

And everything is working fine up until this point.

Now, I have a section in the backend of my application which allows users to define values of a "Block". So in this case, there is a `title` and `subtitle` text field. I want to have a preview of the component just below the form and the component would update dynamically based on the values in the form.

I have done this so far:

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" value="Some title">
```

Any help on how I would accomplish all this, would be helpful.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So just pass model title into component. Not sure what is your problem exactly? `<block-heading class="component-block" title="{{ title }}"  ...`

Comment: We can have another binding called isPreview and depending on its value (true/false), have an ng-if with static markup in the component's template.. not sure what exactly ur looking for..

Comment: @dfsq I tried what you said, and now, when I add text to the title field, I do see that value represented as the title attribute of the component, but the component itself does not update. Any ideas why?